# MySQL select using replace with concat

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I select all the matching words?

Here's my query:

```
WHERE CONCAT(column) LIKE CONCAT('%', REPLACE('field', ' ')'%')
```

Can anyone please help? Thanks.

Comment: All words matching to what?  Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: sql fiddle is a great platform for building a minimal, verifiable example of your tables and queries.  It's worth taking some time to get to know it .

Comment: i wanted correction on my above sample query.i know its like this `Select * from table WHERE CONCAT(column) LIKE CONCAT('%', REPLACE('field', ' ')'%')`

Comment: Please provide a relevant and minimal sample data showcasing your requirements, and expected output. Ref: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)